# Divs with fixed and dynamic width and vertically centered image

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left-colum">Some paragraphs of text</div>
    <div class="right-column"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

The right-column has the width of the image, but since it holds different size images its width is unknown. I want the left-column to take whatever is needed but with a max-width of 150px. I also want the image in the right-column centered vertically.

In the end it should look like the example below, but I have a hard time time getting this together. How would I do this?

[image]

edit: I have the following CSS, but the right-column isn't at 100% height so I can't start trying to vertically center the image yet:

```
.parent{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.left-colum{
    float: left;
    max-width: 150px;
}
.right-column{
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What element and why sets such a large `.parent` height?

Comment: What CSS do you have now?

Comment: Added the CSS. @Lucio: because it's necessary for the content it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use nested `flexbox` see the comments inline.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.parent {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh; /*viewport height*/
}
.left-column {
    background: pink;
    max-width: 150px;
}
.right-column {
    background: gold;
    flex: 1; /*expand*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /*center x*/
    align-items: center; /*center y*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left-column">Some paragraphs of text</div>
    <div class="right-column">
        <img src="//dummyimage.com/100">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flex display on columns and set `display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content: center` on right div and `max-width: 150px;` on left div. Also be aware of vendor prefixes for browsers in order to properly use flex property.

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.left-column {
     max-width: 150px;
    display: flex;
}
.right-column {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display:center;
}
```

Comment: BTW, if that helped you, please accept the answer. thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply this. The flex property is unknown to me. And you're mentioning that I should apply a max-width on my right column? I think you mean the left column? If it's not too much to ask, could you give me the classes styles in your answer please?

Comment: Thank you for the example. It isn't giving the desired effect as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/xqd4jqeL/2/